# What is best way to find first half of True's in boolean numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

Here is the problem:

Take a numpy boolean array:

```
a = np.array([False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False])
```

Which I am using as indexes to panda dataframe.  But I need to create 2 new arrays where they each have half the True's as the original array.  Note the example arrays are much shorter than actual set.

So like:

```
1st_half = array([False, False,  True,  True,  False, False,  False, False])
2nd_half = array([False, False,  False,  False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

Does anyone have a good way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find true indices

```
inds = np.where(a)[0]
cutoff  = inds[inds.shape[0]//2]
```

Set values equivalent before and after cutoff:

```
b = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=bool)
c = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=bool)
c[cutoff:] = a[cutoff:]
b[:cutoff] = a[:cutoff]
```

Results:

```
b
Out[65]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

c
Out[64]: array([False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

There are numerous ways to handle the indexing.

Comment: I think your `cutoff` line has a typo.

Comment: @DSM is right, it should read `cutoff = inds[inds.size//2]` or `...[inds.shape[0]//2]`